# How to directly connect server behind reverse proxy with client

Tags: apache, proxy, reverse

The question relates to Apache, mod_proxy.

I have a site with external IP=X, internal IP=10.0.0.1 powered by Apache which works as reverse proxy for images:

```
ProxyPassMatch *.\.(jpg|gif|png) http://10.0.0.2/handle_image.php
```

When a client with IP=Y connects to IP=X requesting logo.jpg, Apache on 10.0.0.1 connects to 10.0.0.2 and retrieves image from it; then it sends the image to the client on Y. This means that image data passes through 10.0.0.1.

I want the client on Y to get data directly from 10.0.0.2 while keeping connection to X; i.e. the client thinks it gets data from X but actually pumping image from 10.0.0.1 so that server network at X is not loaded by image transfer.

As I understand it should be kinda TCP session hijacking by server at 10.0.0.2 of the connection between X and Y.

How do I do this?

EDIT
To make me more clear, I add an graphic.[image]

Answer (score 0):

The actual approach you describe is not possible with a browser. You cannot initiate a connection from the backend *to* the browser, it has to come from the browser to the backend.

What you can do is use websockets to create a full duplex connection from the backend to the client through the proxy. Thus, the backend can continually push new things to the browser, but it goes through the proxy which just tunnels it from the backend to the browser in raw form.

With httpd (Apache), this is possible by using [mod_proxy_wstunnel](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html)
Alternately, you can achieve this with `mod_lua`, but that's a whole other story.

Comment: What about this: http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Virtual_Server_Administration/s2-lvs-directrouting-VSA.html

Comment: That is a specific network setup using ARP.
You would have to have administrative access to the core network of your hosts to set this up. It cannot be done via httpd alone.

Comment: I'm root. Is there another solution than LVS Direct routing?

Comment: root is not enough, you would have to have access to the physical routers in place to set this up. If you do not have access to change the actual network setup, then no, you cannot work around it like you want to. Responses must go through the proxy server. If you do have access to the routing setup, then you should ask in the appropriate channels.